# Getting the Rows in Table 1 That does not Match Table 2 Using JOIN on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, select, join, left-join

Hi I have the Query Like this :

```
 SELECT TT2.whs_code, 
        TT2.pdt_code, 
        TT2.fresh_frozen_status, 
        TT2.case_dt_yyyymmdd, 
        TT2.qty_cases, 
        TT2.qty_wt 
FROM #TempTable2 AS TT2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempTable AS TT1 
    ON TT1.whs_code = TT2.whs_code 
    AND TT1.pdt_code = TT2.pdt_code 
    AND TT1.fresh_frozen_status = TT2.fresh_frozen_status 
    AND TT1.case_dt_yyyymmdd = TT2.case_dt_yyyymmdd
```

The Thing is I want to select the columns in #TempTable2 That are not existed in #TempTable1 based on

```
whs_code, pdt_code, fresh_frozen_status, case_dt_yyyymmdd
```

means that lets say a set of data 
`1,115G,FR,20160222` is in #TempTable1 So If a set of data Say
`1,115G,FR,20160223` has to be selected or
`1,115G,FZ,20160223` has to be selected or
`2,115G,FR,20160223` has to be selected
but not `1,115G,FR,20160222`

Comment: You look to be almost all the way there. Simply add the `WHERE tt1.fresh_frozen_status IS NULL` to your query to show all the rows in T2 that aren't in T1

Comment: I need the unique selection based on set of whs_code,pdt_code,fresh_frozen_status,case_dt_yyyymmdd 
fresh_frozen_status is never null in any table

Comment: With a left-join off tt2 with tt1 as you have shown, tt1.fresh_frozen_status will be null when there is no matching tt1 record for a tt2 record - that's why you need to add the 'WHERE' clause

Comment: So is there a chance of whs_code,pdt_code,case_dt_yyyymmdd will also be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use NOT EXISTS.

```
SELECT TT2.whs_code, 
    TT2.pdt_code, 
    TT2.fresh_frozen_status, 
    TT2.case_dt_yyyymmdd, 
    TT2.qty_cases, 
    TT2.qty_wt 
FROM #TempTable2 AS TT2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM #TempTable AS TT1
                    WHERE tt1.whs_code = tt2.whs_code
                       AND tt1.pdt_code = tt2.pdt_code
                       AND TT1.fresh_frozen_status = tt2.fresh_frozen_status
                       AND TT1.case_dt_yyyymmdd  = TT2.case_dt_yyyymmdd 
                   )
```

Comment: Why to Use TOP(1), Little Confused

Comment: This is done for performance reasons. Basically what this is doing is it finds the first one and moves on to the next row. You can read this and hopefully learn a little more. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2011/04/05/to-top-or-not-to-top-an-exists/

Comment: That Works Great Thanks a Lot.